# Prevent/stop/disable automatic updates on ubuntu desktop?

Tags: gnome, 10.04, updates

I'm using Lucid, and I have this in (System/Administration/Update Manager):

[image: lucid-auto-update-1]

... that is, apparently I have turned off automatic updates.

However, occasionally, when I listen to music, I can hear it interrupt and I can see intense hard disk activity; usually when it stops, I get a new icon in the toolbar, with an exclamation mark:

[image]

If I right-click this icon, and click Preferences, I'm taken again to Update Manager, just on the first tab.

Thus, even if I have disabled automatic updates, automatic updates still run?

How do I get automatic updates to be disabled completely??

Comment: Have you tried to use the **Check** button in Update manager to actually check if you have the latest versions of your programs?

Answer (score 0):

I usually edit the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file to do this.